# What does "with whom the actor is cohabiting as a parent" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, relative-clauses, whom

I am having trouble understanding this sentence:

> A family or household member means a person with whom the actor is cohabiting as a parent, or guardian.

Is the actor the parent or guardian or is the actor the child?

Comment: The actor is playing the role of parent or guardian and in fact is cohabiting with the previously mentioned family or household member in that role.

Comment: @SvenYargs Thanks.  Can it be correctly interpreted the other way as well, where the actor is playing the role of the child?

Comment: @mattz No, that's not a possible reading. That would have to be “a person who is cohabiting with the actor as a parent or guardian”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guilty party is 'with whom,' a standard shortcut that introduces confusion.

Let's remake the original sentence into a few shorter ones:

A family or household member means a person. What about **that person**? That person is someone **with whom** the actor is cohabiting. In living together with that person, the actor connects **with** that person (that's the **with whom**) as a parent or guardian connects with that person.

In the end, there are two requirements: The actor lives with the person, and the actor is that person's parent or guardian. The original version avoids repeating 'person' by using 'with whom.'